# Python: Ways to monitor program is running

Tags: python, monitoring, stateless

**Background info:**

I have built a program `main.py`, that is built to perform work at a stateless level (meaning if something fails, it will get requeued/database etc separately)...

**Problem:**
I am trying to figure out how to monitor this `main.py` program from my linux instance.

`Main.py` runs and threads out multiple workers, however I want to monitor and ensure the system is still healthy to 'perform work'...

- How can you do this from a single script level and determine that it is no longer working?

My Ideas:

- Create a status notification to syslog stating it is healthy... and trigger on no longer receives? (if that is possible)
- Linux maybe provides a way to monitor that system is healthy?
- last one is creating a TCP/Socket level query mechanism to check for status...

I hope i'm describing the problem right... I'm trying to ensure program is not only running ,but processing and can process[?]

Comment: Side Note: 
*In Networking when you have a service behind a load balancer, you have 'health checks' and LB queries backend to see if they are active...*  .. this is kind of the idea but from a python script without creating sockets (hopefully).

Comment: This question is kind of broad.  There are lots of options for "monitoring" a service: you can write status information periodically to a file, and check that file. You can provide a REST API that can be queried for status information. You could publish metrics via some remote metrics API. Which of these and the many other choices makes sense in your situation depends entirely on your requirements.